# Unable to set EventGrid Subscription Advanced Filter in Azure CLI using a Variable

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to make a dynamic Azure CLI Task in Azure DevOps that will let us reuse the task.  My biggest issue right now is dynamically setting the --advanced-filter on the command.

I have looked at the documentation here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/how-to-filter-events, and the only place it shows using a variable for the filter is in the PowerShell command not the Azure CLI.  I have tried to replicate that syntax for the CLI, but it fails.

Here is the command I am trying to run.  I took the syntax for the filter from the above Microsoft doc.

```
$eventSubscriptionFilter = @{operator="StringContains"; key="data.messageTypeUri"; Value=@("myUriHere")}

az eventgrid event-subscription create --endpoint-type azurefunction --name $topicSubName --source-resource-id $topicid --endpoint $functionEndPoint --deadletter-endpoint $storageid/blobServices/default/containers/$containername --advanced-filter @($eventSubscriptionFilter)
```

If I run this without the --advanced-filter it works perfectly, but as soon as I add --advanced-filter I get this error:

```
az : usage error: --advanced-filter KEY[.INNERKEY] FILTEROPERATOR VALUE [VALUE ...]
```

Is this what I am going to have to do?

```
--advanced-filter data.$myMember StringContains $myValue
```

I am not even sure if that is going to work.  I am going to have to hard code it in there, and that kills the ability to make this dynamic.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify `--advanced-filter` in Azure CLI command, it should be like `--advanced-filter [key] [operation] [value]`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#examples)

For example(I test it in Powershell)

```
$key="data.Message"
$opreation="StringContains"
$value=@("test","test1")
az eventgrid event-subscription create 
 --name $topicSubName 
 --source-resource-id $topicid 
 --endpoint $functionEndPoint 
 --deadletter-endpoint $storageid/blobServices/default/containers/$containername 
 --advanced-filter $key $opreation $value
```

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks.  The error it was throwing was throwing me for a loop.  Wasn't sure if it was expecting something different.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for butting in, but can you also explain me how to set the advancedFilter values in an ARM template, please? I've set it like this `"advancedFilters": [ { "key": "subject", "operatorType": "StringContains", "value": "inputs" } ]`, and the key and operator gets set, but not the value.